# Get Webpage Title from URL in PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql, post, html-parsing, file-get-contents

I'm trying to receive a certain url through post and **scrape** the title of that HTML page. Then, I will store the title of the page into my MySQL Database.

Before Implementing this feature to my actual online server, I tested the page_title function (which is the custom function that reads the title of the HTML page of a given URL) on my local server, and it worked fine. Here is the code I used on my **local server**.

```
<?php 
   $link = $_POST['link'];
   function page_title($url) {
   $fp = file_get_contents($url);
   if (!$fp)
       return null;

   $res = preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/siU", $fp, $title_matches);
   if (!$res)
       return null;

   // Clean up title: remove EOL's and excessive whitespace.
   $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $title_matches[1]);
   $title = trim($title);
   return $title;
  }

  $title= page_title($link);
  echo $title;   ?>
```

However, when I used this exact same code on my online server to actually push the data in to the MYSQL Database, the function seems to return **nothing** but an empty string. As a result, whenever I check my php myadmin, nothing appears on the "title" column. Can anyone please tell me what I can do to make this work? Thank you!

Comment: are you trying to scrape SSL enabled sites?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest simplifying it by doing this (remove the comments as it is too much info):

```
<?PHP

# Get the HTML from a web page
$html = file_get_contents("http://whatever.url");

# Get all HTML titles in to an array (this is your own code)
$res = preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/siU", $html, $titleArray);

# Get the first array entry - and an empty string if the tag does not exists
$title = isset($titleArray[0]) ? $titleArray[0] : "";

# Remove HTML tags from the string
$title = strip_tags($title);

# Show the title - convert HTML tags just to show it does not have any
echo "[". htmlentities($title) ."]";

# Save it to your database ...

?>
```